# Sqlite Data not displaying

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, uwp

```
Application
x:Class="sqlasynctest.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:sqlasynctest"
xmlns:viewModel="using:sqlasynctest.ViewModel"
RequestedTheme="Light">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <viewModel:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

        if (!SimpleIoc.Default.IsRegistered<IDal>())
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDal, Dal>();
        }


        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }
    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
        }
    }
    public static void Cleanup()
    {
        // TODO Clear the ViewModels
    }

}
```

MainViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly IDal _iDal;

    private IList<User> _user;

    public IList<User> Users
    {
        get { return _user; }
        set { Set("Users", ref _user, value); }
    }
    public MainViewModel(IDal dal)
    {
        _iDal = dal;
        LoadDataCommand = new RelayCommand(async () => await LoadData());
    }
    public ICommand LoadDataCommand { get; private set; }
    public async Task LoadData()
    {
        Users = await _iDal.LoadAllUser();
    }
}
```

MainPage

```
<Page
x:Class="sqlasynctest.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:sqlasynctest"
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"> 
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" SelectionMode="Single"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" Margin="120,0,0,40">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Table And Methods are fine but i think binding is wrong , help me 
LoadData() 
Method is not called any where .

I got a solution

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var viewModel = (MainViewModel)DataContext;
        if (viewModel != null)
        {
            viewModel.LoadData();
        }
```

I don't like to touch MainPage.cs 
any other way to do this in xaml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `LoadDataCommand` in your view model, but it is not called from anywhere. There is no magic here – you have to invoke it either from XAML, or from code-behind file. Here's the way this can be done in XAML:

1. Install `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed` NuGet package.
2. Modify XAML of your main page:

   ```
   <Page
   ...
   xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
   xmlns:c="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"> 

   <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
       <c:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
           <c:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadDataCommand}"/>
       </c:EventTriggerBehavior>
   </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

   <Grid ...>
   ```
3. Remove overridden `OnNavigatedTo` method from the code-behind file.
4. `LoadDataCommand` will now be invoked each time `MainPage` is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems is that your collection is a `List`. It does not notify the UI about chnages. User an `ObservableCollection` instead and it will start to work.

Comment: Its not working, I didn't call the LoadData() . OnNavigatedTo call then it's working, but I don't like to use OnNavigatedTo method , I want that in xaml